# PHP not displaying MathJax from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mathjax

Hello I'm stuck rendering MathJax from MySQL database. Since I couldn't find the right answer I would like to ask about rendering MathJax from MySQL database with PHP.

The MathJax code renders when I write it through text editor directly to the page.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wkkvA.png)
But when I save it to the database and try to `echo` saved data it doesn't apply MathJax style.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQsql.png).

I'm storing the data as TEXT in MySQL.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPrIc.png)
I'm adding MathJax to website through

```
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
```

```
<script id="MathJax-script" async src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>`
```

I've tried to read the MathJax docummentation but i wasn't able to find solution. I've also tried googling i couldn't find answer that would help me.

Comment: Is there any kind of mathjax javascript involved when you edit and save the code?

Comment: No there is not should there be ?, I edited question of how i include MathJax on webpage.

Comment: Well show us how you read from the database and place into the HTML of the page

Comment: To display content I'm using `<?php echo $item['body']; ?>` to read from database I'm using `<?php
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM feedback';
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $feedback = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); 
    ?>` and looping through feedback and displaying body as in first code in this comment.

Comment: @randomGuy You should check the documentaion of MathJax. Most of the time you need to do something with the container `div` where you place your code (from database) in, to do the rendering.

Comment: @Foobar Thank you for your answer. I've tried looking at the documentation and I couldn't find the solution. I thought the answer is on this page [link](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html) but I've added `MathJax.typeset()` above the including script and it still didn't work. Could you please point me at the right page on the documentation ?

Answer (score 0):

I tryed this and it works:

```
<head>
<script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es6"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="has-math">
<div id="preview">\(\sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1){6}\)</div>
<br> Original: \sum_{i=0}^n i^2 = \frac{(n^2+n)(2n+1)}{6}
</div>
<script>
MathJax.typeset();
</script>
</body>
```

So put your content in the 'preview' div:
`<div id="preview">\(\)</div>`

like `<div id="preview">\(1+1\)</div>`

The rest is on you :-)

Did research here on the fly and is a very complex tool.

Notice: This just shows what you have saved and loaded from db and you can not edit it.